# PHP/Oracle how to deal with a lot of Selects

Tags: php, sql, oracle12c

I'm trying to find the best way to run this query 240 times in a loop that changes 'value' depending on how many assets we have.

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT field_date,field_time,field3 FROM table WHERE field3 = 'value' ORDER BY field_date DESC, field_time DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;`

Doing it one at a time is taking too long to load the report, I've looked into Bulk Collect but am not sure if this is the best way and cannot find any straightforward documentation for implementing this with php by passing an array (I presume).

Sorry to sound dumb but all the documentation just isn't making sense and I'm looking for an in-context example. I presume Oracle will return something PHP knows how to put into an array?

Comment: Could you not just use an OR and do it all in one statement? SELECT * FROM (SELECT field_date,field_time,field3 FROM table WHERE field3 = 'value' OR field3 = 'value2' ... ORDER BY field_date DESC, field_time DESC) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

Comment: Hi Matt, what value changes and is the 240 fixed or variable?  Have a look at the Oracle functions - you can use oc_fetch_array and wrap that in a var_dump to view whether the structure of the result is what you are looking for.

Comment: leighBicknell 240 times isn't fixed, it depends on how many assets we have.
@cherrysoft so value is basically an asset number, the number of assets we have can change, and the value is different for each asset. Not sure oc_fetch_array would work in that instance?
What's being checked is who last logged onto the asset basically.

Comment: Why not pass an array? Or store the possible values in a temporary table and join to it?

Comment: @kchason That might work, but not sure how to do it. Just found oci_bind_array_by_name but not sure how to use it so reading up on it now. Any examples would be greatly appreciated.